# Can't open Markdown preview in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Exactly what it says on the tin: `command 'markdown.showPreview' not found` pops up every time I try to open the preview of a plain `.md` file. I tried uninstalling every MD-related extension, to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

Just restarting VSCode cleared this error for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem when running VS Code as Administrator.
The preview works fine running under my user account.

Comment: I have this same issue. I thought it was one of my extensions based on what I had read on other SO threads. tried disabling all extensions, but MD preview still wouldn't work. only worked once I opened VS Code normally instead of using an Administrator instance of Terminal to open VS Code.